# why File object changed when i sent it from the front-end to the backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file, react-admin

I'm using react for the front-end, nodejs for the backend, I'm creating an admin for my website using react-admin, the website basically is a store, i'm trying to create new product and save it in the database, everything is working but i have problem with uploading image.
at the end of the day we know that image is a file so when i do print the file in the fornt-end i get this:

```
File {path: "usersForm.png", name: "usersForm.png", lastModified: 1616064578818, lastModifiedDate: Thu Mar 18 2021 11:49:38 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", …}
lastModified: 1616064578818
lastModifiedDate: Thu Mar 18 2021 11:49:38 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
name: "usersForm.png"
path: "usersForm.png"
size: 156658
type: "image/png"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
```

by the way this is create function that defined in the dataprovider:

```
reate: (resource, params) => {
    
    console.log(params.data.Images[0].rawFile);// this shows the file object 

    httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/Create`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
    }).then(({ json }) => ({
      data: { ...params.data, id: json._id },
    }));
  },
```

Now if you take a look at the create function you can see that it sends a post request, with a custom data (params.data),so when this data received by the backend (nodejs), and i when i do print to see that file i'm getting just this :

```
{ path: 'usersForm.png' }
```

this is how i console.log the file :

```
  console.log(req.body.Images[0].rawFile);
```

i want the file as it was in the front-end with it's all information so that i can save where i want using multer.
**my question**:why the file changed after sending it ?
if there something i'm doing wrong you can guide you can show me the right path.

Comment: Look at here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#extending-a-data-provider-example-of-file-uploa

Answer (score 0):

the solution of this problem is sending file with form data
inside create of dataprovider add this

```
 const formData = new FormData();

  for ( const param in params.data ) {

    // 1 file
    if (param === 'Images') {
      formData.append('file', params.data[param].rawFile);
      continue
    }

    // when using multiple files
    if (param === 'files') { // files remplace with your params data 
      params.data[param].forEach(file => {
        formData.append('files', file.rawFile);
      });
      continue
    }

    formData.append(param, params.data[param]);
  }

  return httpClient(`myendpoint.com/upload`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData, // but in body formdata 
  }).then(({ json }) => ({ data: json });
```